# uploader convert any format image into jpg image

Tags: php, upload, converters, jpeg

working on an uploader and added a switch statement to it to convert any image .png, .gif, .bmp, into a jpg.

But it doesn't seem to work, is anyone able to explain me the issue of why it passes through the switch and stil keeps the file format as .gif or png?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['addpart']))
    {
    $image = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($image as $key)
        {
        $fileData = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]));
        $fileName[] = $name . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];
        move_uploaded_file($key, "image/" . end($fileName));
        copy("image/" . end($fileName) , "image_thumbnail/" . end($fileName));
        $images = "image_thumbnail/" . end($fileName);
        $new_images = "image_thumbnail/" . end($fileName);
        $width = 100; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
        $size = GetimageSize($images);
        $height = round($width * $size[1] / $size[0]);

        switch ($size[2])
            {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $images_orig = imagecreatefromgif($images);
            break;

        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
            break;

        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $images_orig = imagecreatefrompng($images);
            break;

        default:
            die("Unknown filetype");
            }

        //$images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
        $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
        $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
        $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
        ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width + 1, $height + 1, $photoX, $photoY);
        ImageJPEG($images_fin, $new_images);
        $i++;
        }

    echo 'Uploaded<br />';
    echo 'Main Image - ' . $fileName[0] . '<br />';
    echo 'Extra Image 1 - ' . $fileName[1] . '<br />';
    echo 'Extra Image 2 - ' . $fileName[2] . '<br />';
    echo '<hr>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Why are you passing `$size` to the switch statement and expect `IMAGETYPE`?

Comment: @B-and-P: $size is an array and $size[2] is a PHP image type constant, *e.g.* IMAGETYPE_GIF.  That part ought to work.

Comment: @BobBrown I was thinking about using $size['mime'] as the case, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: It looks like your `$fileName` array stores original extensions, that is what you are echoing.

Comment: @B-and-P What do I need to do for this to work?

Comment: It is imagejpeg, not imageJPEG. Also, I believe your saved image is jpeg encoded, but you are typing the initial extension and also, the filename probably contains the original extension.

Comment: Just at the end of the for loop try this out: var_dump(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

Comment: @LajosArpad , so i would use which variable ? var_dump(pathinfo($images_fin,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

Comment: $new_images is the variable to use

Comment: @LajosArpad , I got this **string(3) "jpg" string(3) "png" string(3) "gif"** as a result, what can be done from that? http://i.imgur.com/4AXCd5M.png

Comment: You are converting images to jpeg but saving them to the original filename + extension. You should use filename + '.jpg'. You should use another array for new filenames

Comment: @B-and-P , thanks for the assistance, where exactly would I change the file name from another and into a .jpg? up in the code, im changing the file original name to a username+ current time.

Comment: I don't see where you are adding user name and timestamp, all i see is a `uniqueid`.

Comment: @B-and-P I managed to make it add a .jpg format to the image, but, the original file that i moved stays animated, any reason for that?

Comment: @B-and-P I added it over here **$fileName[] = $name . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['name'] . 'jpg';** it seems to work perfect, one more thing if possible any way to freeze the gif so when it uploads it doesnt stay animated?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the assistance that everyone gave on this uploader.

The features are

- compact code
- unique file identifier
- numbers files with a +1 increment, starting with 1 as the first file
- can add a word infront of it, for example a session username or a
  first name
- can add as many file boxes as needed
- converts images to jpg in both the original format and new thumb
  version.
- thumb can set a max width and the height becomes proportional so it
  doesn't become distorted
- 2 different directories to separate thumb and original
- can grab image data so it can be inserted into a database very
  easily.

Here is the final code, it is a useful snippet for any body who wants to rip it apart.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['addpart'])) {
    $image = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
    $name  = $_POST['username'];
    $i     = 0;
    $i2    = 1;
    $id    = uniqid();
    foreach ($image as $key) {
        $fileData   = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]));
        $fileName[] = $name . '_' . $id . '_' . $i2 . '.' . $fileData['name'] . 'jpg';
        move_uploaded_file($key, "image/" . end($fileName));
        $images     = "image/" . end($fileName);
        $new_images = "image_thumbnail/" . end($fileName);
        $width      = 100; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
        $size       = GetimageSize($images);
        $height     = round($width * $size[1] / $size[0]);

        switch ($size[2]) {
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $images_orig = imagecreatefromgif($images);
                break;

            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
                break;

            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $images_orig = imagecreatefrompng($images);
                break;

            default:
                die("Unknown filetype");
        }

        //$images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
        $photoX     = ImagesX($images_orig);
        $photoY     = ImagesY($images_orig);
        $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
        ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width + 1, $height + 1, $photoX, $photoY);
        ImageJPEG($images_fin, $new_images);
        $i++;
        $i2++;
    }

    echo 'Uploaded<br />';
    echo 'Main Image - ' . $fileName[0] . '<br />';
    echo 'Extra Image 1 - ' . $fileName[1] . '<br />';
    echo 'Extra Image 2 - ' . $fileName[2] . '<br />';
    echo '<hr>';
}

?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
username - <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="50" /><br>
Main Image - <input name="images[]" type="file" id="images[]" size="50" accept="image/jpeg" /><br>
Extra Image 1 - <input name="images[]" type="file" id="images[]" size="50" accept="image/jpeg" /><br>
Extra Image 2 - <input name="images[]" type="file" id="images[]" size="50" accept="image/jpeg" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="addpart" value="Upload" /><br>
</form>
```